# showing animation Non-stop in java fxml

Tags: java, fxml

I want to show my animation (TransitionDuration and TransitionPath) non stop

I try setCycleCount(-1) but when the animation is finish my node is stop and when animation play it plays again
I want to remove this stopping and my animation play non-stop

```
         PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        pathTransition.setNode(bullet);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(-1);
        pathTransition.setPath(new Circle(353,200,120));
```